# Why we need polynomials to prove that $1,a,a^2,\dots , a^{n-1}$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm reading Lang's "Undergraduate Algebra", here:

> [image]

It's not clear to me why proving that that is a field, we need to invoke polynomials. I'll also add the statement and proof of this [previous theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5BA8.png) which I suspect may have something to do with it but I can't spot it.

Comment: Well, you have to construct inverses somehow and, since all you know about $\alpha$ is that it is algebraic, it seems natural to consider its minimal polynomial.

Comment: @lulu That being said, they never state explicitly that $p$ is this minimal polynomial. If you as the reader can't pick up on that (which isn't obvious unless one is already familiar with what they're doing), then it seems rather non sequiteur.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah, in the previous text, Lang talks about a minimal degree polynomial. Is that it?

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, I noticed that.  It's odd...$p(x)$ is undefined, but it is central to the argument.  But at one point the author tacitly assumes that $p(\alpha)=0$ so it's pretty clear what was intended.

Comment: @lulu Again, it's pretty clear if you already know what's going on. Pedagogically, for a beginner reader, it's a massive blunder.

Comment: @lulu Perhaps he talked about it in an earlier part of the book. I'm having lectures about it, the professor used a bit of Hungerford's book and then we jumped straight into Lang's book for field theory.

Comment: @Arthur  Well, I've always had problems with that text.

Comment: @BillyRubina  Sure, but it's easy to define it in context.  The Theorem statement could have just read "...Let $n$ be the degree of its irreducible polynomial, $p(t)$,...".

Comment: We need the polynomial for a number of things. If $\alpha$ is an arbitrary number why would the span of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^6$ be a field, if we have no way of making certain that, for example, $\alpha^4\cdot\alpha^3=\alpha^7$ is in there? Also, as lulu explained, we need to make sure that, for example $\alpha^5-\alpha+1\neq0$ and that $1/(\alpha^5-\alpha+1)$ can be written as a linear combination of powers of $\alpha$. The fact that $\alpha$ is a zero of an irreducible degree seven polynomial takes care of both kinds of problems.

Comment: for the vector space viewpoint I recommend Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. Like Greub, he makes things as coordinate free as possible, with determinants at the very end only. Easier reading than Greub...Section 8.C is Characteristic and Minimal polynomials. I think (Jyrki would know in detail) that just taking the operator as multiplication by $\alpha,$   expressed in the basis $1,\alpha, \alpha^2, $

Comment: @WillJagy  Ah, thank you.  That certainly does make the definition of $p$ clear.

Comment: @BillyRubina How did you imagine this proof without polynomials? For instance, to prove that the product of $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \alpha^i$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b_j \alpha^j$ is again of this form you somehow how to get rid of the terms $a_i b_j \alpha^{i+j}$ with $i + j \geq n$. That is, you have to get rid of the terms of degree $\geq n$, but it's the language of polynomials that makes it possible to talk about degree in the first place. It can surely be done with induction, but it will likely be cumbersome and a repetition of arguments that have been made for polynomials already anyway.

Comment: @WillJagy I posted the top of the page in the question. See the link in the text.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I guess I figured out: We have $x\in \{1,a,a^2,\dots , a^{n-1}\}$ each of those elements has a minimal polynomial associated with it, right? Now the powers of $a$ must be a field and the associated polynomials must be a field. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the powers of $\alpha$ must be a field and the associated polynomials must be a field" and while it is true that every power of $\alpha$ has a minimal polynomial, I don't see how that helps you. But I now realize your problem may be somewhere else: the claim is not that the powers $1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}$ _form_ a field, it is that their linear span is a field.

Comment: So you're looking at the set $\{ a_0 + a_1 \alpha + a_2 \alpha^2 + \dots + a_{n-1} \alpha^{n-1} \;\mid\; a_0, \dots, a_{n-1} \in F\}$ and the claim is that that set is a field. The elements of that set look suspiciously like the (evaluations at $\alpha$) of polynomials over $F$ of degree $< n$, which is why the polynomials show up.

Answer (score 1):

here is the top of that page and previous

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]